# What is correct method for observing multiple events in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I need a data table to update each time a different date range, # of decimals to display, or a common vs all set of variables is chosen by the user.  The code below works, but I don't think it's "correct".  The three variables I need the code to respond to (input$descr_daterange, input$descr_radio, and input$descr_decimals) are located within the renderDataTable function.  That doesn't seem like the right way to do this.

```
    observeEvent(input$descr_daterange, {
            descr_date_inds <- reactiveValues()
            descr_date_inds$begin_ind <- min(which(substr(inputData$qcdata$LDT,1,10) == input$descr_daterange[1]))
            descr_date_inds$end_ind <- max(which(substr(inputData$qcdata$LDT,1,10) == input$descr_daterange[2]))
            
            output$data_descr <- renderDataTable({
                    description <- descr(inputData$qcdata[descr_date_inds$begin_ind:descr_date_inds$end_ind,],transpose = TRUE, stats = input$descr_radio)
                    description <- description[-which(row.names(description) == 'RecNum'),]
                    
                    if ('N.Valid' %in% colnames(description) & 'Pct.Valid' %in% colnames(description)){
                            description <- description[,-which(colnames(description) == 'N.Valid' | colnames(description) == 'Pct.Valid')]}
                    
                    description <- round2(description[,2:ncol(description)],input$descr_decimals)
                    return(description)
                    autoWidth = TRUE
                    options=list(pageLength = 50)
            })
    })
```

I've seen code examples that list the variables like this:

```
  observeEvent(c(input$descr_daterange, input$descr_decimals, input$descr_radio),  
{...})
```

However, I get warnings that only the first of the list is being used.  How do I code this to get it to to work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close: put all reactive inputs to cause a trigger within braces.

Try this:

```r
observeEvent({
  input$descr_daterange
  input$descr_decimals
  input$descr_radio
}, {
  descr_date_inds <- reactiveValues()
  descr_date_inds$begin_ind <- min(which(substr(inputData$qcdata$LDT,1,10) == input$descr_daterange[1]))
  descr_date_inds$end_ind <- max(which(substr(inputData$qcdata$LDT,1,10) == input$descr_daterange[2]))
  
  output$data_descr <- renderDataTable({
    description <- descr(inputData$qcdata[descr_date_inds$begin_ind:descr_date_inds$end_ind,],transpose = TRUE, stats = input$descr_radio)
    description <- description[-which(row.names(description) == 'RecNum'),]
    
    if ('N.Valid' %in% colnames(description) & 'Pct.Valid' %in% colnames(description)){
      description <- description[,-which(colnames(description) == 'N.Valid' | colnames(description) == 'Pct.Valid')]}
    
    description <- round2(description[,2:ncol(description)],input$descr_decimals)
    return(description)
    autoWidth = TRUE
    options=list(pageLength = 50)
  })
})
```

By-the-ways:

1. `reactiveValues()` tend to belong *outside* of reactive blocks, and used/referenced within them. I don't know the rest of your app nor how you intend to use them, so it might be that you don't need it at all (and are just using its list/env functionality), in which case you are carrying unneeded overhead by doing it this way.
2. You should never use `&` or `|` within an `if` conditional unless it is wrapped in `any` or `all` or some aggregating function. `if` requires its conditional to be exactly length 1, whereas `&`/`|` are vectorized logical ands/ors, meaning they can be length 0 or more.

   Even if both sides of the `&` are length-1, there is still a reason: `&&` short-circuits, `&` does not.

   ```r
   ### short-circuiting
   TRUE || stop("hello")
   # [1] TRUE

   ### not
   TRUE | stop("hello")
   # Error: hello
   ```

   Lastly, it's a bit declarative, in that by forcing yourself to use `&&`, you have to think about the length of the conditional. By using `&`, you're *implying* (to whomever is reading/using your code) that you will accept a result of length other than 1 ... which doesn't always work cleanly for `if`.

Comment: Thank you.  That does work, but now I get a "-Inf" or "Inf" warning with the min(which(substr(inputData$qcdata$LDT,1,10) part of the code.  I don't quite understand that warning since input$descr_daterange is the expression part of the observeEvent code.  I tried putting the three lines that get input$descr_daterange in a separate observeEvent function and using req(input$descr_datarange) for the renderDataTable function, but the warning still occurs.  Also, renderDataTable isn't recognizing the options list, either. 
 Anyway, this behavior seems really strange to me.  Thanks again!

Comment: `min(which(FALSE))` returns `Inf`, `max(which(FALSE))` returns `-Inf`, so make sure that you are certain of a match 100% of the time.